# ClickHouse Unsupported JOIN ON conditions

Tags: clickhouse

I've a SQL query that works in PostgreSQL, but doesn't work with Clickhouse. But I want to migrate it from Postgres. Query:

```
select 
  u.counter_id, 
  r.date_of_visit, 
  sum(r.sessions) as sessions, 
  sum(r.pageviews) as pageviews, 
  u.utm_campaign, 
  u.utm_source, 
  u.utm_medium, 
  u.utm_content, 
  u.utm_term 
from 
  metrika.utm_for_collect u 
  inner join metrika.utm_sessions_report r on u.counter_id = r.counter_id 
  and (
    u.utm_campaign = r.utm_campaign 
    or u.utm_campaign is null
  ) 
  and (
    u.utm_source = r.utm_source 
    or u.utm_source is null
  ) 
  and (
    u.utm_medium = r.utm_medium 
    or u.utm_medium is null
  ) 
  and (
    u.utm_content = r.utm_content 
    or u.utm_content is null
  ) 
  and (
    u.utm_term = r.utm_term 
    or u.utm_term is null
  ) 
group by 
  u.counter_id, 
  r.date_of_visit, 
  u.utm_campaign, 
  u.utm_source, 
  u.utm_medium, 
  u.utm_content, 
  u.utm_term
```

It throws an error:

*Unsupported JOIN ON conditions.
Unexpected '(utm_campaign = r.utm_campaign) OR (utm_campaign IS NULL)': While processing (utm_campaign = r.utm_campaign) OR (utm_campaign IS NULL). (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION) (version 22.7.2.15 (official build))*

Any ways to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`? That's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just tried, same error

Comment: try don't use Nullable types
and use `u.XXXX=""` instead of `u.XXX is null`

Comment: Tried, still same error